# tab bar controller and placing objects

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a Tab Bar Controller in Interface Builder with 3 navigation controllers. IB is not allowing me to put more than one object in a view controller. For instance, I can't place both an image and a rect button or two images etc...

anyone know if i'm making a mistake here?

i hope i explained it clearly enough. i've attached a screen shot

thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're trying to do?

Comment: i just did. that was good timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, I would have another xib file that defines the SessionViewcontroller's view.  And that would be where I would design the SessionViewController, laying out the elements of the view in that xib.  And then in your Tab Bar Controller's Session View Controller, look at inspector and reference the class as that SessionViewController.

I would not design the whole application's set of views from the MainWindows.xib file.  I am not sure you can do that.

Comment: No problem.  There are tons of gotcha's developing on the iOS.  Glad I can help.  In fact, even after 5 months of development, I just learned that function of viewDidUnload.  Definitely read up on it if you get the chance on here.  It will matter to you once you start having multiple views and the iOS frees up your views due to memory management.  You'll need to take care to free up your subviews or you'll get memory leaks all over the place.  Good luck!